# Question about twitter api

Tags: api, twitter

I want to create a simple Twitter application, but I have a problem. I want to show the user information about his followers, but this requires one API request to get a list of all user *IDs* following him, and then many additional API requests to get the user *information* corresponding to the user IDs that were just fetched. Is it possible to get user info for many followers in *one* request?

Comment: what are you asking? whether there's a twitter api function to do it all in one call?

Comment: @TZHX Hmmm...i can use a few functions in one call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Followers method:
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/followers.xml ([Twitter API Documenation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554748/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3a-statuses%C2%A0followers))

It returns detailed information about each follower.

Comment: Each call using this API method will return 100 followers, which should be exactly what you're looking for. The documentation has been updated to include Twitter entities; here is the current link: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/followers